# Shape key on top of the modifier stack?

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to create a shape key/blend shape on top of the modifier stack.
Like using an edit poly modifier in the end of a modifier stack.

Basically a non destructible medthod for creating some details at the end of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  However, this is almost always going to be asked as an XY problem, where the questioner thinks this is the solution to some other problem Y, and they just need to figure out how to do X-- but in fact understanding X won't solve the other problem, and other solutions to Y exist.  So I don't expect this answer to be useful to you, but I'll answer the question anyways.

To approach this problem, we first have to know what shapekeys *are*, but it turns out that's pretty simple.  A shapekey is just a per-vertex, object space vector.  When we run a shapekey at 1.0, we add that vector to the position.  When we run two shapekeys, we add both those vectors to the position.  When we run a shapekey at 0.5, we add half of that vector to the position.

So if we want to evaluate a shapekey at some arbitrary position in the modifier tree, we can do it by using a different modifier that *also* just adds a vector, in object space, to the vertex position.  The displace modifier does exactly that:

[image]

To do this, we're going to need a decent UV map, one that exists inside the 0,1 UV square, one that doesn't have any overlap, because we need to bake a displacement map from our shapekey.

Here, I baked the base position to a floating point, non-color texture and packed.  Then I baked the shapekey position to a new texture.  Then I baked the shapekey position minus the base position.  This forms an XYZ displacement map representing the shapekey.  (Here, it's a little bit off, because I forgot to turn off subdivision for the bake.)  This could almost certainly be optimized, but it's the basic procedure.

I can use that XYZ displacement map in a displace modifier, from UV coordinates, in local space, using RGB->XYZ mode.  My strength is 1.0 (this corresponds to the strength of the shapekey.)  My midlevel is 0.0.  I tell it to use a texture for the displacement, and set that texture up as an image, referencing my baked Diff.  Let's look at it with a modifier before the displacement:

[image]

At first, that looks very odd.  What's happening?  We're armature deforming, and I've used my root bone to turn Suzanne upside-down.  Then, we're applying our shapekey *after* the armature.  We're doing it via a displace modifier, but it's the same thing, it's just translation of each vertex by an object-space vector.

Shapekeys are in local space, and our mesh's local space hasn't changed.  Instead, its vertices have deformed *inside* of its unchanging local space.  So the shapekey is doing exactly what it's supposed to do: it's translating the vertices in the positive Z.

That's not usually what people want.  That's why knowing how to do this is unlikely to actually help you, and why shapekeys are designed to run before other modifiers, and why there aren't a lot of tools to make it easy to make them operate afterwards.  But, on the chance that this is exactly what you want, that's how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **geometry nodes** to save vertex positions and then another geometry node tree to restore it or interpolate between the old position and new position (which is what shape keys do, they interpolate between sets of vertex positions).

1. Create a new file with default cube.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> to subdivide.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> twice to go to Geometry Nodes workspace.
4. Click a button in the center of screen [image] to create a new node tree.
5. Use this setup:

[image]

6. In modifiers stack, name the output attribute `oldpos`:

[image]

7. Add some modifier that doesn't remove or add geometry (that wouldn't work with shape keys too, as it messes with indices):

[image]

8. Repeat p. 4. [image]
9. Use this setup:

[image]

10. **Optional:** you may want to press <kbd>N</kbd> key to open a side-panel and modify the input attribute to properly describe what it is:

[image]

11. In modifiers stack, define the input attribute [image]
12. You can now interpolate by dragging the *Mix RGB* node Factor slider:

[image]

You may think it's useless as you could just control the modifier's factor, but this way you get a shape-key-like direct (simplest) interpolation, plus you can actually deal with indices changing by something like *Transfer Attribute* in proximity mode...

Comment: I want to have a "sculpt layer" on top of the modifiers. I don't know how to use that for that purpose.